# iOS native file loader fails to return all selected photos, when the photos are stored in iCloud

Tags: ios, file-upload, icloud, photo

On an iOS device, where the photos are backed up to iCloud, the native uploader can fail to return all selected photos... if you click "Open" too soon.

That is:

- you are on an iOS device
- you are attempting to upload multiple (e.g. 50) photos
- the photos are stored in iCloud
- you're not on a super fast network
- you select the photos through the native uploader Media | Photos
  **- you don't wait for all the spinners to complete before clicking "Open"**
- then the FileList will return with, at most, one file.

**If you do wait for the 'spinners' to complete before clicking "Open", then the FileList is returned with all the expected files.**

Here is some very simple code to reproduce:

```
<input type="file" name="img" accept="image/*" multiple onchange="loadFile(event)">

<script>
var loadFile = function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.files)
};
</script>
```

Ignoring the fact that the native iOS uploader experience is poor: it appears to hang while it processes all the selected photos...

...one would expect the full file list to return irrespective of when one clicks "Open"